# local (html /js) files in assets folder with android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

this is my `OnCreate` method .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv_setting = wv.getSettings();
    wv_setting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/home.html");
}
```

and this is my `home.html` file .

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <body>

 <h1>Hello WebView !</h1>

 </body>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 </html>
```

this is my `app.js` file .

```
 alert('its working');
```

And i have `home.html` and `app.js` files in assets folder .

But its not working ( no alert message ).

Which part is wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

alert is not supported by android WebView .

Answer (score 0):

Use `wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())` in conjunction with what you already have. That will enable things like alert.